# How to get rid of the extraneous output from a rspec / capybara / poltergeist test

Tags: rspec, capybara, poltergeist

Using rspec 3.2.2 / capybara 2.4.4 / poltergeist 1.6.0 (both phantomjs 1.9.0 & 2.0.0) produces extraneous output prior to the completion of each test:

[image]

phantomjs 1.9 was installed from kubuntu 15.04 repository. phantomjs2.0.0 was compiled.

It's related to either poltergeist or phantomjs (doesn't occur with selenium).

Would appreciate being able to either redirect or eliminate the extraneous output as it makes test output difficult to read or use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that logging is enabled for the cycle2 jQuery plugin? Do you see the same output in the browser JS console?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by 'browser JS console'. Could you please elaborate.

Comment: thanks. No, the same output does not appear in the browser JS console. I also found a snap2code illustration of the problem dated 25Sep2014 - https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/173876/Ruby---Capybara-for-remote-server-accept, which is the only other reference to the problem I have been able to locate. Unfortunately was unable to find the original post to see what the resolution, if any, might have been. Nevertheless the problem persists.